# Using Puppeteer/Headless Chrome to report performance metrics

Tags: performance-testing, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm experimenting with Puppeteer to use headless Chrome and trying to find how to report the time for first-paint. I've been looking through the [Chrome DevTools Performance API](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance/#event-metrics) and noticed there is an `Performance.metrics` but when I subscribe to the event its never triggered.

```
const client = page._client
await client.send('Page.enable')
await client.send('DOM.enable')
await client.send('Performance.enable')
client.on('Performance.metrics', (obj) => {
   console.log({obj})
})
await page.goto('http://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
```

But the event observer is never fired. Any suggestions on how I can observe the metrics data from Performance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are asking about [First Meaningful Paint](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BR94tJdZLsin5poeet0XoTW60M0SjvOJQttKT-JK8HI/view) you can get it by using:

```js
await page.goto('http://example');

await page.waitFor(1000);
const performanceMetrics = await page._client.send('Performance.getMetrics'); 
console.log(performanceMetrics);
```

I wrote an article ["Test website performance with Puppeteer"](https://michaljanaszek.com/blog/test-website-performance-with-puppeteer#firstMeaningfulPaint) with a chapter dedicated to measuring `FirstMeaningfulPaint`.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I needed. I thought I needed to use an observable on a watched event instead of the `send` command returning an object.

Comment: By the way, @Everettss, your website is down at this moment. :(

Comment: @Kangaroo.H Thanks for reporting! I'm sorry for this temporary inconvenience.

Comment: @Everettss It's back online. Good job!

Comment: The waitFor is really critical. Why do you select 1000? What if First Meaningful Paint isn't happening in these 1000 ms...

Comment: @Tobi I wrote it as a mental shortcut. In linked article, I've explain it how to change this line to proper code. Check line: "If you spot the smelly part of code `await page.waitFor(1000);`..."

Comment: ps: article can be find in web archive now - http://web.archive.org/web/20210514063755/https://michaljanaszek.com/blog/test-website-performance-with-puppeteer/